# Report Viewer - Horizontal scroll bar appears cut off or only half displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssrs-2008

I have a Report Viewer control in an aspx page. the control is used to render several reports. Some of the report have large number of rows and hence the horizontal scroll bars are necessary to scroll the content to the right side.

But my issue is the horizontal scroll bar is only half visible and cannot be clicked to scroll to the right side. I tried resizing the report height and width still no solution. I read that setting AsynRendering to false solves this issue but I cannot set this to false. Are there any other solutions for this? Please help.

Comment: can you post the relevant code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem. Just added a style attribute to the reportviewer control.

style="margin-bottom:80px;"